# How I could deserialise this XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have problem with deserialization of this XML file:
[xml - kursy walut](http://rss.nbp.pl/kursy/xml2/2010/a/10a092.xml)

I have pasted this xml as special to make classes which will be serialized.

I don't have any idea how to deserialise it, it's not easy file to make it for me :(

I need `przelicznik` and `nazwa_waluty` to use as data in application.

Is it possible to deserialise this xml structure?

Comment: Just read it by the LinkToXml

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
    //if the xml isnt local (you should have the permission to read the document):
      Uri uriXml = new Uri("http://rss.nbp.pl/kursy/xml2/2010/a/10a092.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(uriXml.ToString());

        //if the document is local:
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\10a092.xml");

        //get all the elements from the Xml
        var elements = (from xnode in doc.Descendants("pozycja") select xnode).ToList();

        foreach (var node in elements)
        {
            //your data is here
            Console.WriteLine(node.Element("nazwa_waluty").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(node.Element("przelicznik").Value);
        }
        Console.Read();
```